# Setting IGMP Version on Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, igmp

I have a piece of software written "out there" (e.g. no source code available) that allows me to use it in multicast mode. I'm trying to use this software on a network that, for technical reasons, can only use IGMP Version 2.

My OS is Windows 7 (64-bit, though I doubt that makes a difference). So far my searches have only given me Windows XP & Windows Server solutions, all of which involve editing the registry. In addition to the usual reasons (aka "registry paranoia"), I hesitate to edit the registry in this case because this particular network is not the only one that I will be using; I have not problems at all in all the other networks I try using multicast on.

Is there a straightforward way to force this software onto IGMP V2?

Thanks!

John Price

Answer (score 0):

As far as I remember, adding IGMPVersion=3 to HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\Tcpip\Parameters is the only way to solve your problem.

Anyway, there is another creepy solution - just write a little daemon, that will sniff for IGMPv3, parse data from it and send IGMPv2 packets =)